# Validate form before adding an extra text fields

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

IF you check my **[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/17/)**, there is a form which is validated  properly. You can click on submit button to check how it works.

And there is another button called Add Person,which creates a group of text fields.

My question is, the Add person button should create text fields only when the form is fully filled. If form is not filled and user clicks on Add person button then it should show an alert.

Here is my code

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#commentForm").validate();

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",           
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required",
            'country': {
    required: true
 }
        },

        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy",
            country: "Please select an option"
        }
    });


clicks = 0;
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('.attnd2').show();
  $('div.loop').show();
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        if(clicks>1){
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });
        }
        else{
        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });


    }

    }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `rules` for `dynamically created elements` like

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(frm) { 
        var flag=true;
        var $allElemReq=$("input[required],select[required]");
        for(var ind=0;ind<$allElemReq.length;ind++)
        {
            elem=$allElemReq[ind];
            if(!$(elem).val())
            {
                flag=false;
                $(frm).validate().element($(elem));
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
            alert("submitted!"); 
        else
            alert('Not submitted');
    }
});
```

**Additional** add a `required attribute` for the `compulsory fields`

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/22/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    if(!$("#signupForm").valid()){
        return;
    }

    $('.attnd2').show();
    $('div.loop').show();
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        if(clicks>1){
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
            });
        }
        else{
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
            });


        }

    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T3nuC/)

Comment: But this still adding extra fields,. What I need is to restrict adding fields until the entire form is filled

Comment: @Sowmya fixed it now, missed `!` in the condition

Comment: I need to show msg below the button as well. like please fill the above fields before this

Comment: @Sowmya that could be a different question I think... you can look at `errorClass` and `errorPlacement` options anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/21/)**

```
$('a').on('click', function () {

    if($('#firstname').val() != '' && $('#lastname').val() != '' && $('#email').val() != '' && $("#agree").prop('checked') == true && $('#country').val() != '') {

    $('.attnd2').show();
    ('div.loop').show();
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        if(clicks>1){
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });
        }
        else{
        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });


    }

    }
    } else {
        alert('Please fillup field before add');
    }      
});
```